# Adding htaccess and htapassrd to heroku site

Tags: .htaccess, heroku, .htpasswd

I'm trying to temporarily password protect my Heorku app with the .htaccess and .htpasswrd files in the root of the app.

I'm getting a 'Internal Server Error' with the following codes and can't figure out where I'm going wrong

**.htaccess**

```
AuthUserFile .htpasswd
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Access"
Require valid-user
```

.**htpasswrd** (MD5 encrypted)

```
rob:$apr1$MRsSwhFN$buG0YTSOezeY8YJ32LXnT1
```

Comment: check your apache error log for the details

Comment: Go read the docs on how the file-path argument to `AuthUserFile` is interpreted.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like your path is off.

> As of July 2016, some subtle changes are necessary on heroku-php-apache2. Please note that the path to the .htpasswd file no longer contains the www directory and that the .htpasswd file should be in the webroot as well.
>
> Create an .htaccess file in the webroot:

```
AuthUserFile /app/.htpasswd
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Access"
Require valid-user
```

> Create a .htpasswd file, also in the webroot:

```
htpasswd -c .htpasswd [username]
```

> Commit local changes. Deploy to Heroku.

https://gist.github.com/bbrewer97202/3316425

Comment: Thanks, I'm adding the following the .htpasswd file > htpasswd -c .htpasswd rob and can't progress past the login box

Comment: So you have a login box now? Good that means you set it up properly. If you can't login, it must be due to the `.htpasswd` file. Have you tried changing it? What happens when you attempt to fill out the login box?

Comment: Thanks Nathan. Yep, I have a login box but really user of the exact details I should have in the .htpasswd file. I've tried *htpasswd -c .htpasswd rob* *htpasswd -c .htpasswd rob:test* but not getting any closer

Comment: Well, the value after `rob:` should be MD5 hashed.

Comment: Is your original `.htpasswd` file the same as your original post?

Comment: Thanks for your help @Nathan, I maybe confusing things and confusing myself. my .htpasswrd file reads 'rob:098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6' with this being MD5 encoded but get a 'Internal Server Error'